# Any security vulnerabilities with this custom SSO scheme

Tags: security, openid, single-sign-on

I am going to use the following scheme for implementing SSO -

Initial login -

1. Whenever a user loads a client app, he is redirected to the SSO login page.
2. Once the user logs in, an encrypted cookie token is set on the client and the value is also stored in the session.

Accessing another app -

1. When the user load another client app, he is redirected again to the SSO login page.
2. The SSO module first checks if the encrypted cookie exists and then compares the value with the value in the session.
3. If both of these match, it redirects the user back as authenticated.
4. Or else it asks the user to enter username / password.

Are there any security vulnerabilities with this scheme?

Thanks,
Murtaza

Comment: What's in the encrypted cookie?

Comment: The cookie contains the session id for that user.

Comment: Consider using HTTPS instead of "encrypting" the sessionID. If the encrypted sessionID is accepted as the sessionID, then for all intent and purposes, it's the sessionID.

Comment: Thanks. One more question, how do I secure the communication between my client app and the SSO module. I mean how do I verify that something is not spoofing as the SSO module. If I just use SSL will that be enough ? Or should I encrypt the identity token being returned  back to my client app ? and the server and client both have the key avalaible beforehand.

Comment: Yes, use SSL/TLS. If this SSO login page is presented in a browser via HTTPS, the browser will validate the server for you, otherwise, it's up to your app to store the server's public certificate or fingerprint and verify it against the one presented by the server's SSL cert.

Comment: Thanks. Also is it possible that someone can manipulate the cookie in the browser. Say the server returned the id "bob". Now lets say the id "joe" has superuser privileges, so someone may change the cookie token and gain superuser privileges? How do I protect against that?

Comment: A session ID is generally a long random string, not a user name. The server generates the session ID and associates it with a specified user on the server. That session ID is what goes in the cookie. You can't guess someone else's session ID and you can't sniff it since you're using HTTPS.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14146/discussion-between-murtaza52-and-marcus-adams)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The design seems fairly standard for an SSO scheme.  Of course, even if the concept is secure, vulnerabilities can arise in the implementation of the scheme.  For instance, a secure implementation would need to guard against compromise of the SSO authentication cookies and vulnerabilities in the identity assertion to the relying system.  Additionally, vulnerabilities in the authentication mechanism itself (such as weak passwords) could be amplified in an SSO environment where a single credential can be used to authenticate to multiple applications.

The use of both the encrypted cookie and session to identify the end user to the relying applications may be redundant, and may not be effective if the motivation is to defend against session hijacking attacks.  If a HTTP request that includes these cookies is ever sent in cleartext, both the session ID and encrypted cookie cyphertext would be sent in the clear, potentially opening a spoofing vulnerability.  (Of course, the cookie cleartext would not be sent, but an attacker would only need the cookie's cyphertext content.) To mitigate this threat, the session cookie should be set as secure and the SSO login page accessible only through SSL.

If the motivation for an encrypted cookie is to allow the credential to be saved past the session lifetime, then care is needed to use appropriate cryptographic practices (e.g., key management and use of standard encryption algorithms).  Of course, the cookie should be marked as secure to ensure (for practical purposes) that it is not sent in cleartext.  Other countermeasures such as updating the cookie after each assertion to prevent duplication, and limiting the lifetime (e.g., requiring reauthentication every *x* days) may be warranted.

The scheme also requires that the verifier make an identity assertion to the RP after successfully authenticating the end user.  There are several standard protocols for this, such as [OAuth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OAuth) and [OpenID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenID).

Finally, the user should have recourse to terminate the SSO session to prevent unauthorized access when the user leaves the session.

Of course, the assurance requirements of the relying systems needs to be considered -- what is the risk (in terms of likelihood and impact) if the SSO system is compromised?  As the risk increases, so too does the cost-effectiveness of strategic and operational countermeasures (e.g., risk and vulnerability assessments) to defend against compromise.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. Three points I am taking away which were lacking in my implementation - SSL, update the cookies after each assertion , and expire them after x period. I was also mainly worried about the identity assertion of the provider, but as I am using OpenID, that should be fine as you have mentioned. Thanks once again !